# почему segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm

посмотрите перед меткой `debug`. там вызов функции `inet_ntoa`. я передаю ей регистр, который `int` содержит ip адрес клиента. и в этой функции происходит ошибка. но как такое возможно? я же передаю единственный параметр и очищаю на всякий случай `rax`.

```
global main

extern socket
extern setsockopt
extern bind
extern listen
extern read
extern perror
extern exit
extern close
extern accept
extern write
extern read
extern inet_ntoa
extern strlen
extern strncpy
extern printf

PF_INET          equ     2
SOL_SOCKET       equ     1
SO_REUSEPORT     equ    15
SOCK_STREAM      equ     1
SIZE_SOCKADDR_IN equ    16

section .text

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 128
;[rsp + 0]        int sock
;[rsp + 4]        int optval
;[rsp + 8]       char buffer
;[rsp + 24]       struct sockaddr_in client
;[rsp + 40]       int len of ip
;[rsp + 44]       char *ptr
;[rsp + 52]       size of struct sockaddr_in
;[rsp + 56]       int sock_client
;[rsp + 60]       struct sockaddr_in server
    xor rax, rax
    mov rdi, PF_INET
    mov rsi, SOCK_STREAM
    mov rdx, 0
    call socket
    cmp rax, 0
    jg set_option_socket_reuse_port
error_socket:
    lea rdi, [error_socket_string]
    call perror
    xor rax, rax
    mov rdi, 1
    jmp exit_program
set_option_socket_reuse_port:
    mov [rsp + 0], eax      ; sock
    xor rax, rax
    xor rdi, rdi
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor r8, r8
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov [rsp + 4], dword 1        ; optval
    mov edi, [rsp + 0]      ; sock
    mov esi, SOL_SOCKET
    mov edx, SO_REUSEPORT
    lea rcx, [rsp + 4]      ; optval
    mov r8d, 4
    call setsockopt
    cmp rax, 0
    je bind_socket
error_set_option_reuseport:
    lea rdi, [error_socket_opt_reuseport]
    call perror
    jmp exit_program
bind_socket:
    xor rax, rax
    mov ax, [server_port]
    xchg al, ah
    mov [rsp + 60 + 2], ax
    mov [rsp + 60], word PF_INET
    mov [rsp + 60 + 4], dword 0x0100007f;
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov edi, [rsp + 0]    ; sock
    lea rsi, [rsp + 60]   ; struct sockaddr_in server
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov edx, SIZE_SOCKADDR_IN
    xor rax, rax
    call bind
    cmp rax, 0
    je listen_socket
error_bind_socket:
    lea rdi, [error_socket_bind]
    call perror
    jmp exit_program
listen_socket:
    xor rax, rax
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov edi, [rsp + 0]    ; sock
    mov rsi, 0
    call listen
    cmp rax, 0
    je accept_client
error_listen_socket:
    lea rdi, [error_socket_listen]
    call perror
    jmp exit_program
accept_client:
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov edx, [size_msg_accept_client]
    lea rsi, [msg_accept_client]
    mov rdi, 1  ; sock
    xor rax, rax
    call write
    mov eax, 16
    mov [rsp + 52], eax  ;
    lea rdx, [rsp + 52] ; ptr sizeof sockaddr_in
    lea rsi, [rsp + 24] ; ptr sockaddr_in
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov edi, [rsp + 0] ; sock
    xor rax, rax
    call accept
    cmp rax, 0
    jg new_client
error_accept:
    lea rdi, [error_socket_accept]
    call perror
    jmp exit_program
new_client:
    mov [rsp + 56], dword eax
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov edi, dword [rsp + 24 + 4]
    xor rax, rax
    call inet_ntoa
    mov [rsp + 44], rax
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov rdi, [rsp + 44]
    call strlen
    inc eax
    mov [rsp + 40], eax
    xor rax, rax
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov edx, [rsp + 40]
    mov rsi, [rsp + 44]
    lea rdi, [rsp + 8]
    call strncpy
    xor rax, rax
    lea rsi, [rsp + 8]
    lea rdi, [msg_connect_client]
debug:
    call printf

exit_program:
    call exit
    leave
    ret

section .rodata
; -------------- сообщения об ошибках -----------------------
error_socket_string            db 'Не удалось открыть сокет', 0x0
error_socket_opt_reuseport     db 'Не удалось установить опцию для сокета SO_REUSEPORT', 0x0
error_socket_bind              db 'Не удалось привязать сокет', 0x0
error_socket_listen            db 'Не удалось задать параметр для прослушивания', 0x0
error_socket_accept            db 'Не удалось принять клиента', 0x0
msg_accept_client              db 'Ожидание новых клиентов', 0xa, 0x0
size_msg_accept_client         dd $ - msg_accept_client
msg_connect_client             db 'Подключился клиент: %s', 0xa, 0x0
; -------------- глобальные переменные, которые легко искать ----------
server_port     dd     8020
```

а вот компиляция

```
all:
    nasm -f elf64 server.asm -o server.o
    gcc server.o -no-pie -o test
```

я посмотрел код функции `inet_ntoa` с помощью `objdump -M intel -d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so | less`, и нашел там функцию.

```
0000000000132aa0 <inet_ntoa@@GLIBC_2.2.5>:
  132aa0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  132aa4:       41 54                   push   r12
  132aa6:       89 f8                   mov    eax,edi
  132aa8:       41 89 f9                mov    r9d,edi
  132aab:       4c 8b 25 de 82 0b 00    mov    r12,QWORD PTR [rip+0xb82de]        # 1ead90 <h_errlist@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0xc70>
  132ab2:       0f b6 d4                movzx  edx,ah
  132ab5:       c1 e8 18                shr    eax,0x18
  132ab8:       40 0f b6 cf             movzx  ecx,dil
  132abc:       be 12 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x12
  132ac1:       64 4c 03 24 25 00 00    add    r12,QWORD PTR fs:0x0
  132ac8:       00 00 
  132aca:       41 c1 e9 10             shr    r9d,0x10
  132ace:       41 89 d0                mov    r8d,edx
  132ad1:       48 8d 15 bc 75 08 00    lea    rdx,[rip+0x875bc]        # 1ba094 <_libc_intl_domainname@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x2c8f>
  132ad8:       48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  132adc:       4c 89 e7                mov    rdi,r12
  132adf:       45 0f b6 c9             movzx  r9d,r9b
  132ae3:       50                      push   rax
  132ae4:       31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  132ae6:       e8 f5 23 f3 ff          call   64ee0 <__snprintf@@GLIBC_PRIVATE>
  132aeb:       58                      pop    rax
  132aec:       4c 89 e0                mov    rax,r12
  132aef:       5a                      pop    rdx
  132af0:       41 5c                   pop    r12
  132af2:       c3                      ret
```

но что именно не так не могу понять, потому что в отладчике библиотека недосигаема для дизассемблера.

Comment: там тоже самое.

Comment: Перед `call accept` вы не сохраняете значение регистра `rbp`. Там потом мусор. Может надо было [rsp-..]

Comment: сейчас проверю. но rbp вроде правильный после accept, так как в edi потом помещается ip адрес, который должен быть. но щас проверю.

Comment: @AlexGlebe а почему значение rbp надо сохранять перед accept?

Comment: всё таки можно добраться до `inet_ntoa` в отладчике и посмотреть код. ошибка работы происходит в snprintf, которая вызывается в `inet_ntoa`.

Comment: @xverizex, к этой проблеме возможно не имеет отношения, но ты неправильно работаешь с локальными переменными: стек растёт вниз, так что они должны адресоваться или как `rsp+N` или как `rbp-N`, так что весь стек выше main'а рушится... собственно это скорей всего вызвало сложности с отладкой...

Comment: по ошибке — у меня всё крашится на `strlen` в `debug`, но оно и понятно — ты передаёшь ей только половину адреса в `edi`... с вызовами `strcpy` и `printf` дальше всё тоже не хорошо... зачем ты вообще используешь строковые фунции на ассемблере? не говоря уже о том, зачем вообще копировать строку в свой буфер на стеке?

Comment: @Fat-Zer чтобы показать какой ip адрес подключился.

Comment: @xverizex, я про то что просто скорми то что вернул `inet_ntoa` `printf`'у...

Comment: @Fat-Zer так я потом еще буду использовать этот ip. я пока strlen не проверял. но в `inet_ntoa` был segmentation fault. или у вас уже работает это?

Comment: с `inet_ntoa` УМВР... кстати, ещё согласно amd64/System V ABI вершина стека по идее должна быть выровнен на 16 байт... скорей всего на практике это не так сильно критично, но лучше соблюдать при вызове сторонних функций...

Comment: @Fat-Zer покажите рабочий код пожалуйста

Comment: @xverizex, [вот](http://dpaste.com/33815WQ) последние на чём я остановился...

Comment: @Fat-Zer но почему у вас работает с таким стеком, а у меня нет? я сделал исправление как вы говорили, чтобы было так `[rbp - 4]`. посмотрите и скажите что не так? кстати, inet_ntoa возвращает указатель на строку, да, там была ошибка, но до нее не доходит выполнение, так как в inet_ntoa крашится.

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо. ваш код работает, но почему не работает мой? я поменял на rbp - 24 и так далее. по многу раз перепроверил и всё равно не могу понять. отличается ваш от моего кода тем, что вы используете rsp +, а я rbp -. и я решил структуру сервера тоже локальную использовать. но почему мой код не работает?

Comment: @xverizex, вызов `strncpy` неправильный... должно быть `lea rdi, [rsp + 24]`. тоже самое с `printf`'ом... а ещё не тот указатель передаёшь `inet_ntoa`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо. теперь работает.  я выложил рабочую версию сюда. но вот вопрос: почему не сработало с rbp -? ведь если посмотрить сишные программы, то там локальные переменные так адресуются.

Comment: @xverizex, всё работало... ты просто ошибок наделал... да и я в последнем комментарии опечатался — имел ввиду, что нужно просто `mov` на `lea` заменить: `lea rdi, [rbp - 44]` — не из того окна diff'а скопировал.